# Need a collection view remaining the same in landscape orientation as it is in the portrait

Tags: swift, xcode, collectionview

enter image description hereI’m currently working on a project in my class for App Game Development. So I’m basically using an Connect 4 app, and implementing the code to make an app where you can play this classic version along with two extra versions. However, I am struggling with some auto layout issues. I am required to make an app usable on iPad and iPhones. My app runs perfectly on the iPhone because I only am required to use portrait mode due to the small screen size. I have to use portrait and Landscape for the iPad however. I was wondering if you knew how to make it playable on landscape and portrait orientation for the iPad. The game board is all messed up whenever I switch to landscape mode, but in portrait it is perfectly fine.This is my final project of my senior year and it is due by Friday. Could you please help me out with this issue?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Put a width constraint on your collection view to make it narrower.

If you are using leading and trailing constraints, then use their constants to add side padding so the view is narrower. You can change the constant based on the device and orientation.

Neither of these are really the “right way”, but they are something you can get working quickly. Unfortunately, the right way is probably not using UIKit and collection view for games. It’s possible, but they aren’t made for that and therefore sometimes don’t act in the way you expect.